# Webpack not including css in HTML build

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I am new to webpack and react, i downloaded one github project which suits my requirement and when i start my server, i see that css is not getting included in build html file.

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require('pnp-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const paths = require('./paths');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt');
const typescriptFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter');

const publicPath = '/';
const publicUrl = '';
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// Check if TypeScript is setup
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
  const loaders = [
    require.resolve('style-loader'),
    {
      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
      options: cssOptions,
    },
    {
      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
      options: {
        ident: 'postcss',
        plugins: () => [
          require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
          require('postcss-preset-env')({
            autoprefixer: {
              flexbox: 'no-2009',
            },
            stage: 3,
          }),
        ],
      },
    },
  ];
  if (preProcessor) {
    loaders.push(require.resolve(preProcessor));
  }
  return loaders;
};
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    paths.appIndexJs,
    paths.appBuild + '/static/css/main.chunk.css',
  ],
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: false,
    },
    runtimeChunk: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules'].concat(
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
      .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
      .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
    alias: {
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
      'actions': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/actions'),
      'constants': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/constants'),
      'containers': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components/containers'),
      'commons': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components/common'),
      'reducers': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/reducers'),
      'domains': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/domains'),
      'libs': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/libs')
    },
    plugins: [
      PnpWebpackPlugin,
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    plugins: [
      PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),

            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        oneOf: [
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              customize: require.resolve(
                'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
              ),

              plugins: [
                [
                  require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                  {
                    loaderMap: {
                      svg: {
                        ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-prettier,-svgo![path]',
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              ],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              // Don't waste time on Gzipping the cache
              cacheCompression: false,
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
            exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              babelrc: false,
              configFile: false,
              compact: false,
              presets: [
                [
                  require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                  { helpers: true },
                ],
              ],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              cacheCompression: false,
              sourceMaps: false,
            },
          },
          {
            test: cssRegex,
            exclude: cssModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
            }),
          },
          {
            test: cssModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
            }),
          },
          {
            test: sassRegex,
            exclude: sassModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders({ importLoaders: 2 }, 'sass-loader'),
          },
          {
            test: sassModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders(
              {
                importLoaders: 2,
                modules: true,
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
              },
              'sass-loader'
            ),
          },
          {
            exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml
    }),
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
    new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),

    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),

    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
      publicPath: publicPath,
    }),
    // TypeScript type checking
    useTypeScript &&
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', {
        basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
      }),
      async: false,
      checkSyntacticErrors: true,
      tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
      compilerOptions: {
        module: 'esnext',
        moduleResolution: 'node',
        resolveJsonModule: true,
        isolatedModules: true,
        noEmit: true,
        jsx: 'preserve',
      },
      reportFiles: [
        '**',
        '!**/*.json',
        '!**/__tests__/**',
        '!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*',
        '!src/setupProxy.js',
        '!src/setupTests.*',
      ],
      watch: paths.appSrc,
      silent: true,
      formatter: typescriptFormatter,
    }),
  ].filter(Boolean),
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
  performance: false,
};
```

i am just clueless where to edit above code to solve my problem, i also observed that css in build folder has '#' at the beginning

[Project build folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JWzX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to add a css loader to your plugins.  You'll have to

- npm install css-loader style-loader --save-dev
- Add a plugin to  to your webpack.config.js

  ```
     module:{
              rules:[
          // other plugins

          {
              test:/\.css$/,
              use:['style-loader','css-loader']
          }
  ]
  }
  ```

  Now webpack should bundle your css properly. Note you have to make sure you have imported you css file into your application !

  import '../app.css';

Run webpack again and you should see the css inserted in s style tag in the header of your html page